# Какова принципиальная разница между Arrays.stream() и Stream.of()?

Tags: методы, java-stream

Читал, что Stream.of() вызывает Arrays.stream(), что он делает помимо этого?
Никаких различий в результате работы на следующих одинаковых примерах я не заметил:

```
Stream<Person> arraysStream = Arrays.stream(new Person[] {town.get(0)});
Stream<Person> streamOf= Stream.of(new Person[] {town.get(0)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница только в том, что метод `Arrays.stream` принимает в качестве аргумента массив, а метод `Stream.of` описан с использованием varargs:

```java
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values);
}
```

Т.е. во втором случае можно не создавать новый массив, а просто писать:

```java
Stream<Person> streamOf= Stream.of(town.get(0));
```

Есть одна интересная штука: `Stream.of()` массив примитивов  воспринимает как один элемент, массив же объектов он воспринимает так же, как `Arrays.stream()`.  Поэтому следует быть осторожным с `Stream.of()`, когда мы переводим массив примитивов в `Stream<T>`. Но лучше использовать для примитивов специальные классы и методы, например, `IntStream.of()` и т.д.

Comment: Какой хороший ответ в итоге получился!